# Javascript - Ajax Request in SharePoint - Avoid to overwrite variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Actually I have an issue with javascript. I find no solution for this problem yet.
Maybe someone of you could give me a hint.

I have a created a function, which is called by a button click.in SharePoint 2010.
The function should collect all selected / checked documents from a document library and write them into a separate box, I created. To get all selected documents works fine. But in SharePoint I have to load each element individually for details with an asynchronous request. Here comes my problem:

If I select more than one document, the variable "item" will be overwritten because of the "for" loop. In my asynchronous request success function, I use now the variable "item" again to get the details of it. So I always get the data of the last item of my selection. 
Is there a way to avoid this?
Thanks for any help.

Here is my code:

```
function ApproveDocuments() {
var ClientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var LibraryID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var Library = ClientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(LibraryID); //Gets the current Library
var SelectedDocuments = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ClientContext);

for (var currentItem in SelectedDocuments) {
    var item = Library.getItemById(SelectedDocuments[currentItem].id);
    ClientContext.load(item, 'FileLeafRef');
    ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        var newElementHtml = '<div style="float:left;padding:3px;width:50px;"></div>';
        newElementHtml += '<div style="float:left;padding:3px;">' + item.get_item('FileLeafRef') + '</div>';
        newElementHtml += '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
        jQuery("#grol1855InfoDivData").append(newElementHtml);
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onLoadItemFailure));
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor this a bit so that you don't make an http request every time you iterate through the loop, which should also solve your over-write problem. I also declared the variables outside of the loops and make it point to the new version each iteration.

```
function ApproveDocuments() {
    var ClientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var LibraryID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var Library = ClientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByID(LibraryID); //Gets the current Library
    var SelectedDocuments = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ClientContext);
    var fileItems = [], item;

    for (var currentItem in SelectedDocuments) {
        item = Library.getItemById(SelectedDocuments[currentItem].id);
        fileItems.push(item);
        ClientContext.load(item, 'FileLeafRef');
    }

    ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function() {
        var newElementHtml;
        for (var i = 0; i < fileItems.length; i++) {
            newElementHtml = '<div style="float:left;padding:3px;width:50px;"></div>';
            newElementHtml += '<div style="float:left;padding:3px;">' + fileItems[i].get_item('FileLeafRef') + '</div>';
            newElementHtml += '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
            jQuery("#grol1855InfoDivData").append(newElementHtml);
        }
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onLoadItemFailure));
}
```

I would also really advise against writing new solutions that call any of the SOAP services or anything in _vti_bin for that matter; it's just a matter of time before those go away and your stuff won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried `ClientContext.executeQueryAsync` in a loop but have never gotten it to work for similar reasons. I've worked around this before by using Ajax to call the SharePoint lists.asmx web service. For example:

```
var targetUrl = "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
var listName = "Shared Documents";
for (var currentItem in SelectedDocuments) {
  var currentItemId = SelectedDocuments[currentItem].id;
  var soapEnvArray = [];
  soapEnvArray.push("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<soap:Envelope ");
  soapEnvArray.push("xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">");
  soapEnvArray.push("<soap:Body><GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\"><listName>" + listName + "</listName>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<viewName></viewName>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<query>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<Where>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<Eq>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<FieldRef Name=\"ID\"></FieldRef>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<Value Type=\"Counter\">" + currentItemId + "</Value>");
  soapEnvArray.push("</Eq>");
  soapEnvArray.push("</Where>");
  soapEnvArray.push("</query>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<viewFields>");
  soapEnvArray.push("</viewFields>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<rowLimit>2000</rowLimit><queryOptions><QueryOptions xmlns=\"\">");
  soapEnvArray.push("<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>");
  soapEnvArray.push("<ViewAttributes Scope = \"RecursiveAll\"/>");
  soapEnvArray.push("</QueryOptions></queryOptions>");
  soapEnvArray.push("</GetListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
  var soapEnv = soapEnvArray.join("");
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: targetUrl,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems");
    },
    complete: function (msg) {
      if (msg.status == 200) {
        var totalTaskCount = $(msg.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").length;
        $(msg.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {
          console.log(currentItemId + ": " + $(this).attr("ows_Title"));
        });
      } else {
        //Failure
        var errorCode = $(msg.responseXML).find("errorcode").text();
        var errorString = $(msg.responseXML).find("errorstring").text();
        if (errorString.length === 0) {
          errorString = $(msg.responseXML).find("faultstring").text();
        }
        errorString = errorString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

To make SharePoint Ajax requests easier, I would recommend picking up a copy of [SharePoint CAML Query Helper for 2007, 2010, and 2013](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/). Also, although I have never used it, you may want to consider trying the [SPServices jQuery Library for SharePoint](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to simplify the task.